# How to use a certain ruby version?

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, batch-processing, linux-from-scratch

I try to run a script on a LFS Batchsystem. The cluster offers an older version of ruby, so I had to install my gems and rvm locally on my account. Is there a way to run my local installed ruby version on a batch system? My script works fine on my account but not on LFS because mechanize depends on a newer ruby version.

Comment: Will using bundler solve your problem in any way, I am not sure how you run it on LFS.

Comment: Ok, I specificed the gem path in my jobfile and I also used the binary in my .rvm folder. I hope it will work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with directly using the binary version and to define my local gem folder:

```
GEM_HOME=/home/my_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems
/home/my_name/.rvm/bin/ruby-2.0.0-p195 my_script.rb
```

The other solutions do not work, because rvm is not available on the cluster.

Comment: that is just an ugly workaround, you should install/configure rvm properly, which can be done on a single user account. rvm doesn't need to be installed globally to work. You should also look at rbenv/ruby-build, which I prefer and is imo easier: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [rvm](https://rvm.io/) then

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

or to set the default:

```
rvm use --default 1.9.3
```

And obviously, replace `1.9.3` with the version you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Create `.rvmrc` file in your working directory in that you would mention which version of ruby you are going to you like:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@gemsetname --create
```

Now you can install all gems for this particular gemset.